# KVM guests clustering

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I am running KVM with two guests(win server 2003) on Centos 5.5 how can I cluster two win server on KVM?

Answer (score 1):

depends what kind of clustering. for classical A/P MSCS setup you'd need a central storage. For VMs, the easiest route for this would be by using iSCSI.
Keep in mind that you'll need a target that supports scsi3, since that's what windows requirements are for persistent reservations

Having said all that, what is the point of clusterring two VMs running on the same physical host?